# InfluxDBMapper cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring-boot, influxdb

First of all I am really sorry if this question is not valid, but I am new to `influx db` and I am doing some POC to test it. I am using `influx db 1.7.7`
and using spring boot to interact with the db

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

According to [this](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) link, used `write` method some object into `influx db`.

But, I got the following exception:

```
The method measurementByPOJO(Class<capture#1-of ? extends Machine>) is undefined for the type Point
```

Since, its not available in the `Point`. I don't know what i am doing wrong. I need some advice or suggestion.

Also, i tried this [link](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/README.md) and used `InfluxDBResultMapper.toPOJO(...)` method, but it is also not work for me.

```
   @Data
    @Measurement(name = "machine")
    public class Machine {

    //      @TimeColumn
            @Column(name = "time")
            private Instant time;
            @Column(name = "host", tag = true)
            private String hostname;
            @Column(name = "region", tag = true)
            private String region;
            @Column(name = "idle")
            private Double idle;
            @Column(name = "happydevop")
            private Boolean happydevop;
            @Column(name = "uptimesecs")
            private Long uptimeSecs;
    //      @Column(name = "category")
    //      private List<String> category;

    }


    private void writingDataUsingPojo(InfluxDB influxDB) {


            Machine machine = new Machine();

    //      List<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();
    //      
    //      category.add("A");
    //      category.add("B");
    //      category.add("C");
    //      
    //      machine.setCategory(category);
            machine.setHappydevop(true);
            machine.setHostname("local");
            machine.setIdle(10d);
            machine.setRegion("India");
            machine.setTime( Instant.now() );
            machine.setUptimeSecs(100l);




// Exception coming here
        Point point = Point.measurementByPOJO(machine.getClass()).addFieldsFromPOJO(machine).build();



        }
```

Comment: Please, provide your code, where exception is. It looks like, your problem with generics in definition of `Point` class.

Comment: @BSeitkazin updated in the question

Comment: `Point.measurementByPOJO(machine.getClass())` where is the definition of the `Point` class? How `Point` and  `Machine` objects related to each other?

Comment: Also, show the `measurementByPOJO` method fully.

Comment: @BSeitkazin https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java i am using this guide to do my POC , measurementByPOJO you can search here, i feel its inbuilt method.

Comment: @BSeitkazin pls have a look i edited in the question.